# Flutter: Flutter Video Player cannot play a video file TWICE [Video controller cannot be used after disposed]~

Tags: flutter, exoplayer, android-mediacodec, flutter-video-player, flutter-exception

I'm using Official Flutter Video Player Package for my flutter app, but the **displayer is totally black and I also got this error** while displaying it on the screen:

```
E/flutter (10774): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: A VideoPlayerController was used after being disposed.
E/flutter (10774): Once you have called dispose() on a VideoPlayerController, it can no longer be used.
```

Or Sometimes this:

```
V/LGCodecAdapter(  515): LG Codec Adapter start
I/ACodec  (  515): Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  (  515): onAllocateComponent
I/OMXClient(  515): MuxOMX ctor
I/ACodec  (  515): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Loaded
I/ACodec  (  515): Now uninitialized
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515): Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):   android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffff4
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1895)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.configure(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:61)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.configureCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:620)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1110)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1011)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:578)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1420)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:694)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readToFlagsOnlyBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:965)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:811)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:947)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:477)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(  515):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(  515): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(  515):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.428028, -1, null, [1920, 1080, 28.391167], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(  515):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:554)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(  515):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(  515):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(  515):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(  515):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.428028, -1, null, [1920, 1080, 28.391167], [-1, -1])
```

Here is the code for the player:

```
late final VideoPlayerController _videoCtrl;
late final Future<void> _videoCtrlInitializationFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initVideoCtrl();
  }

  void _initVideoCtrl() {
    _videoCtrl = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.videoFile);
    _videoCtrlInitializationFuture = _videoCtrl.initialize();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _videoCtrlInitializationFuture,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot videoCtrlInitSnap) {
        if (videoCtrlInitSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _videoCtrl.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_videoCtrl),
          );
        } else {
          return SizedBox.shrink();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoCtrl.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
```

I try to use `setState(() {})` and pass a new `UniqueKey()` to my `VideoPlayer` widget to create a new video, but the error appears, shows that the controller cannot be used after dispose, although is completely two different widgets.

Comment: Check the official implementation example https://pub.dev/packages/video_player/example and make changes to your implementation. And if the issue still persist let me know.

Comment: @OMi Shah Yes my implementation is the same as the one written in the official doc, and that's the weird part~

Comment: No, it's not as it's in the example

Comment: Actually, I mean I changed my code to the official implementation code, but the error's still there, apologize that I give you some misconceptions @_@

Comment: Looks like it's device-specific issue. Can you confirm by testing on an emulator or another real device

Comment: I tried it both on LG and iPhone 8, but none of them works... I thought it would be a bug of Flutter Framework it self~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is caused by the targetSdkVersion in build.gradle file (app level), so I need to add an extra permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>`

in my manifest.xml file, also set the ios version in podfile to 10 (or above), and done!

Comment: thank you, the only solution in the internet :)

Comment: I edited AndroidManifest but still the same problem :(

Comment: @AnkitParmar I'm not sure if it still works with the newer version of Flutter though, if you're using flutter version "2.5" or above, then it might be a different situation, try 2.3 or something~ :)

Comment: But google Play will not approve the app with this Permission

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `initState` like below, and tell me the status.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _videoCtrl = VideoEditorController.file(widget.file)
      ..initialize().then((_) => setState(() {}));
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem in my code.

i originally had a controller initalized outside of the a pageview builder
and i fixed it by putting the controller further down the widget tree closer to where it was actually being used (i.e. not passing it as an argument to another widget)

I notice then that i would get these explicit debug messages

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(13370): Init c2ef839 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.0] [OP516FL1, NE2213, OnePlus, 31]
I/ExoPlayerImpl(13370): Release ed3786e [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.0] [OP516FL1, NE2213, OnePlus, 31] [goog.exo.core, goog.exo.exoplayer, goog.exo.decoder, goog.exo.datasource, goog.exo.extractor]
```

so possibly check to see if your getting similar release debug messages when your testing.